# Safely pass arguments to a command executed via su

Tags: bash, security

With sudo, it is possible to execute a command as an other user and **really** safely pass arguments to that command.

Example nasty argument:

```
nastyArg='"double quoted" `whoami` $(whoami) '"'simple quoted "'$(whoami)'"'"
```

Expected output, run via a termninal as congelli501:

```
 % echo "$nastyArg"
"double quoted" `whoami` $(whoami) 'simple quoted $(whoami)'
```

Execute as congelli501, via sudo:

```
 # sudo -u congelli501 -- echo "$nastyArg"
"double quoted" `whoami` $(whoami) 'simple quoted $(whoami)'
```

Execute as congelli501, via su (usual escape method):

```
 # su congelli501 -c "echo '$nastyArg'"
"double quoted" `whoami` $(whoami) simple quoted congelli501
```

As you can see, the argument is not safely passed as it is re-interpreted by a shell.

Is there a way to launch a command via su and pass its arguments directly, as you can do with sudo ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing the command as the shell script argument in su seems to work:

```
 # su congelli501 -s "$(which echo)" -- "$nastyArg" "'another arg'"
"double quoted" `whoami` $(whoami) 'simple quoted $(whoami)' 'another arg'
```

Example usage:

```
# Safely execute a command as an other user, via su
#
#  $1 -> username
#  $2 -> program to run
#  $3 .. n -> arguments
function execAs() {
    user="$1"; shift
    cmd="$1"; shift
    su "$user" -s "$(which -- "$cmd")" -- "$@"
}

execAs congelli501 echo "$nastyArg" "'another arg'"
```

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem here is that you are trying to nest quotes.  You would hope `su -c "stuff "with" double "quotes"` to be parsed as `|su|`, `|-c|`, `|stuff "with" double "quotes"|` but it actually gets parsed as `|su|`, `|-c|`, `|stuff |`, `|with|`, `| double|`, `|quotes|` where however the last four tokens are pasted together as one string after evaluation (notice the spaces where the "inner" quotes terminated the ostensible "outer" quotes instead of wrapping inside them).

Within double quotes, `` `whoami` `` gets expanded by the shell *before* anything gets passed to `su`.

What you can do instead is either *(a)* add yet more quoting around the values in `$nastyArg` (pretty much doomed) or *(b)* define it in the context of the shell executed by `su`.  A distinct third option is to *(c)* pass in the value in a way which disarms it, such as on standard input.

```
printf '%s\n' "$nastyArg" | su -c 'cat' congelli501
```

This may seem overtly simplistic, but is really the way to go when you do not have complete trust over what will possibly be evaluated by `root` somehow.

This is one of the reasons `sudo` is preferred over `su`.